# Не загружается файл с русским именем

Tags: php

Привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой: у меня есть загрузчик картинок, который не хочет загружать картинки с русским именем, т.е они загружаются но выдают warning, а на домашнем серваке (denwer) все работает на ура. Кстати файлы с латинским именем загружаются без ошибок, на домашнем сервере php вообще ни на что не жалуется.

```
Warning: rename(../lib/uploads/заявление.png,../lib/uploads/25818860012d2e419530bdd0cd99e9f7.png) [function.rename]: No such file or directory in /home/l/lektor116/public_html/admin/upload.php on line 28
```

Вот код:

```
<?php
    require('../libs/Smarty.class.php');
    define(DEFAULT_TPL,"../templates/admin/");
    include ('smarty/access.php');
    include ('../lib/config.php');
    include ('../lib/functions.php');
    $smarty = new Smarty;
    $smarty->assign("title","Загрузчик фотографий");
    $smarty->assign("nulled_img","http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/lib/img/no_photo.png");

    if($_POST['send'])
    {
         $imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
         if($imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/gif' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/jpeg' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/png') {
          echo "Извините, к загрузке принимаются только картинки JPG,GIF,PNG.";
          exit;
         }

         $uploaddir = '../lib/uploads/';
         $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

         if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
           $md5 = md5($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
           $type = explode("image/",$_FILES['userfile']['type']);
           $file_name = $md5.".".$type[1];
           rename($uploaddir.$_FILES['userfile']['name'],$uploaddir.$file_name);
           echo "Картнинка успешно загружена.";
           $smarty->assign("filename","http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/lib/uploads/".$file_name);
         } else {
           echo "Неизвестная ошибка загрузки. Попробуйте еще раз.";
         }
    }
    $smarty->display(DEFAULT_TPL."upload.tpl");
    ?>
```

Comment: Так переименуйте, задав имя на латинице. Да и вообще, не плохо было бы задавать уникальные имена, дабы не получилось, что будет загружен второй файл с таким же именем, который перезапишет существующий.

Comment: Картинок много, а каждую переименовывать задолбаешься, так что не прокатит.

Comment: @Lektor, кстати, я сразу не заметил, но переименование у вас присутствует, только уже после загрузки на сервер. Поэтому можно загружать файл с каким-нибудь именем аля "tmp_file" и его же переименовывать, но уже с уникальным именем.

Comment: Да не, загрузка то норм, единственное вот нужно исправить косяк с переименованием, потому как на домашнем сервере все ок.

Comment: @Lektor, стоп... Зачем вообще двойная работа выполняется? Почему б сразу на задавать имя при загрузке? В комменте не хватит места, ща напишу ответом.

Comment: Я не совсем вас понимаю, можете кодом показать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
$original_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($original_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // расширение
$file_name = md5(basename($original_name).time()).'.'.$ext; // новое имя файла
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file_name; // полный путь
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Картнинка успешно загружена.";
    $smarty->assign("filename","http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/lib/uploads/".$file_name);
}
```

Comment: Т.е это готовый код? Если всажу его в upload работать будет?
$uploaddir нужно создать, верно?

Comment: $uploaddir - у вас уже определен:

    $uploaddir = '../lib/uploads/';

Comment: @Lektor, не обязательно нажимать "наградить" )) Достаточно нажать на "галку" рядом с ответом напротив вопроса. Тем более, что баллов у вас нет (теперь уже нет).

Comment: Сделал все как вы описали, ошибок и варнингов нет, но вот при запросе данного изображения выдает 404, картинку по имени не находит. Быть может дело в time()?

Comment: Извиняюсь, переменную uploaddir забыл указать, все работает, спасибо!)